# Abp browse from WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, aspnetboilerplate

I try to open a new winForm with abp page. My user has already do login on application via ABP LogInManger and I store my login result.

So when I open the new form with webBrowser component the login that I try to pass doesn't work.

To do login I try:

- OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; set; } but the object it still null. I need to initialize some Owin or is not the correct way?
- I try to reauthenticate with user and password and put header with Bearer but not work

Any idea to solve this issue?

I write a simple case and more details about my solution:
 - WinForm .Net 4.6.1
 - Web Application 4.6.1 based on AbpBolierplate

We'll create a porting from an old .Net solution and add some new functions. About the new functions the UI is on Abp web and not on WinForm, so to allow user to use this new function we open webBrowser embedded (or not) and we try to authenticate via token.
Right today we talk we other collegue and the solution can be do in this way:

- Create a custom controller on Web to allow post token on it
- Auth user inside the controller and redirect to requested page

Comment: Take a look at [MCVE].

Comment: Ok I prepare it next week

Answer (score 0):

this question **has not a short and correct answer**. I'll try to guide you with outlines of solution;

You didn't mention whether you are using MVC or Angular! But if you are using angular it's easier. Just create a RestApi client in your WinForm. Authenticate to website using Http Post to "api/TokenAuth/Authenticate". Store the token and refresh it before it expires.

Use Application services as WebApi endpoints. Add authentication header to every request you make (eg: bearer xxxxxxx_token_xxxxx).

If you are using MVC then you can create your own WebApi to authenticate and use required services.

Long story short; using WebBrowser to authenticate and consume aspnetboiler website is not a convenient way as you'll have to deal with cookies. best practise is using a WebApi for your use cases.

Comment: Thk Alper probably my question is not clear. My web application have all necessary API to allow my win form authenticate on it but I need to use it to re authenticate via web browser. I add a note on my question to clarify them.